# Recursively walking through a directory tree and listing file names

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

I'm trying to walk through a whole directory tree and print out all the file names on a listbox control. I wrote some code but there are errors. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. By the way, this is in C# using WPF in Visual Studio.

Here is the whole project solution in Visual Studio: http://tinyurl.com/a2r5jv9

Here is the code from MainWindow.xaml.cs if you don't want to download the project solution: http://pastebin.com/cWRTeq3N

I'll paste the code here as well.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sourcePath = @"C:\temp\";            

        static void DirSearch(string sourcePath)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath))
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(f);
                    }
                    DirSearch(d);
                }
            }                      
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method inside another method?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your code example.

Comment: What are the exact errors?

Comment: http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/12423735/1024/Anonymous/WpfApplication2---Microsoft-Visual-Studio-%28Adminis.jpg

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a [complete example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974) on the Microsoft support site

The issue here is that you want to *call* `DirSearch` from the event handler, but it appears you're trying to *define* the method `DirSearch` inside the event handler. This is not valid.

You need to change your code as follows:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string sourcePath = @"C:\temp\";
    this.DirSearch(sourcePath);
}

private void DirSearch(string sDir) 
{
    try 
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir, txtFile.Text)) 
        {
            lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
        }

        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
        {
            this.DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: while we're on the topic, how to check for duplicate files? for example, if there are two files with the same file name in two different directories, I want to output only one file name.

Comment: @SteveWay use `if (lstFilesFound.Items.Contains(f)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 19):

Use [GetDirectories() overload accepting SearchOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx):

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
foreach(dir)
{
    ...
}
```

or better [EnumerateFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
foreach(files)
{
    ...
}
```

Notice it performs *lazy* filesystem scan.

Comment: This is for an assignment at my university. The requirement is to use a recursive algorithm.

Comment: The recursive approach has also another advantage. You can handle exceptions at the file level whereas `SearchOption.AllDirectories` will throw without an option to continue with the next file/directory (after logging).

Comment: If you need to be eager instead of lazy, you have `Directory.GetFiles` (the overload with SearchOption - for recursion). I used to need this a few years ago, when there was a bug in Mono, where files were omitted when using EnumerateFiles and returned in GetFiles.

Answer (score 0):

Using reference arguments seems to be working as well. Haven't benchmarked for performance but here is my current solution.

```cs
public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesRecursive(string path)
{
    static void GetFiles(DirectoryInfo dir, ref List<FileInfo> files)
    {
        files.AddRange(dir.GetFiles().OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList());
        foreach (var subdir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            GetFiles(subdir, ref files);
        }
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) return Array.Empty<FileInfo>();
    try
    {
        List<FileInfo> files = new();
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        GetFiles(directory, ref files);
        return files;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Couldn't read files from directory: {path}\n", e);
    }
}
```